# Draggable elements in Windows 8 apps

Tags: drag-and-drop, windows-8, draggable

I am quite a beginner with Windows 8 apps. Does anyone know how to make any element dragable in Windows 8 apps?
I added `draggable="true"` to the HTML elements that I want to be dragable. But still I'm unable to drag them.

Answer (score 1):

Setting draggable=true does not make everything work.  You must hook into the element and write code to handle the manipulation.  See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/Hh761498.aspx as a good place to start.  This sample app may also prove useful http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Input-Instantiable-deda69ca